# APNS Custom Sound

Tags: php, xcode, audio, apple-push-notifications

i want to send a push notification with a custom sound, but always i try, i only hear the default thing.

my sound is named wil.caf and i have it in my xcode project.

this is my php sript to fire the push message:

```
<?php

$message = $_GET["message"];

$deviceToken = $_GET["token"];


$devideToken = dechex ($deviceToken);
// Payload erstellen und JSON codieren

$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 0, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($payload);
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';

$apnsPort = 2195;

$apnsCert = 'apsDevBundle2.pem';



// Stream erstellen

$streamContext = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);



$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

if ($apns)

{

  // Nachricht erstellen und senden

  $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)).$payload;

  fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);



  // Verbindung schliessen

  fclose($apns);

} 

else

{

  echo "Fehler!";

  var_dump($error);

  var_dump($errorString);

}

?>
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6):

Your sample payload is specifying 'default' as the sound to play.  If you want to play a custom sound, make sure the sound file is in the application bundle and specify it as follows (using Apple's example bingpong.aiff sound file):

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => 0, 'sound' => 'bingbong.aiff'
```

Full APNS documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9